# Define a symplectic structure on $G \times_{G_\beta} V$, where $V$ is symplectic

Tags: lie-groups, sg.symplectic-geometry, vector-bundles, group-actions

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group with  algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $\beta $ be  an element in the dual of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. We denote by  $G_\beta$ the stabilizer subgroup of $\beta$ by the cooadjoint action. Let $V$ be symplectic vector space on which $G_\beta$ acts.

So, we have $V$ is symplectic, $G/G_\beta$ is symplectic (since it can be identified with a cooadjoint orbit which is symplectic), How can we  show that $M:= G \times_{G_\beta} V$ is also symplectic ?

Let $[g,v] \in M$, we have $T_{[g,v]} M = T_gG \times T_vV$
How can we define a symplectic form $\omega_{[g,v]}: T_{[g,v]} M \times T_{[g,v]} M \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tangent space is too big. It has rank $\dim G + \dim V$ but it should have rank $\dim M = \dim G - \dim G_\beta + \dim V$.

I think that the tangent space at $[g, v]$ is actually $T_{g} (G/G_\beta) \times T_vV$. On the first factor you have a symplectic form $\omega_\beta$ and on the second factor the symplectic form $\omega_v$. On the whole tangent space you can then take block-diagonal sum $\omega_\beta \oplus \omega_v$.